Esri ArcGIS Pro on RDS
Is it possible to run ArcGIS Pro on a Windows RDS server if the server has a dedicated GPU?
Hoping to find a cost effective solution, to serve a low number of occasional users who are seldom in the office at the same time. Rather than buy 8 new GIS workstations, I'd like to build a shared resource. Ideally Windows Server running RDS on tin, with a dedicated GPU. (Not Virtualized/VDI).
I'm happy with the concept of each profile only having a fixed share of the GPU.
Databases and file-servers would remain on different hosts in the same room. This would just be for the client session. I've seen this done with ArcMap, but that's a different beast with different requirements.
Our searches are providing conflicting advice, and our vendors aren't much help. Keen to hear from anyone with first hand experience who has done this successfully.
This article would suggest it's still supported: https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/improve-performance-of-arcgis-pro-when-running-over-rem-000026552

This is probably better asked of Esri.

I don't know about a multi-user server, but a single user (at a time) shared workstation running Pro over RDP works ok. RDP can be a little laggy when users are not in office, but isn't a deal breaker.

According to that article, it's possible, so what is your question? Have you tried it? What were the results?

@Berend I want to know it's a feasible/workable solution before I spend $20k on hardware. Internet articles say it's possible, but i have vendors saying it isn't and are proposing a $200k solution instead.  (we're trying to build a POC using old gear but stuggling a bit with compatibility of old components).

@user2856 Yep this is precisely what I want to achieve, a multi-user RDS server with shared GPU capability, that is capable of running 2/3/4 sessions concurrently.

You could always try it out first with a VM in Azure or AWS. Btw, what kind of work is this about? I use Pro over Rdp to do things like publishing mapservices, which is fine without gpu. Heavy 3D GIS work probably not so much.

@Berend I don't think a VM will really test the concept of a shared physical GPU, So we are going to build a POC/testbed with old hardware. We have a range of use cases and so depending on how well it performs we may assign it to occasional users or use it as a GIS team workhorse to chug through large batch jobs.

The short answer is yes.
We're currently running: Win server 2022 datacenter with RDS on an old HP DL380 with a NVIDIA RTX A1000 8GB GDDR6.
We've been working on a trial with an old server and our testing results have been positive so far. We've had a 4-5 users use ArcGIS Pro simultaneously performing various tasks and the Server seems to be handling it really well, and is dynamically allocating GPU resource. (we haven't set any profile restrictions)
Note: One limitation we've read about (but haven't verified) is that RDS can only share a single graphics card so multiple cards are out.
